# Maintain random seed for duration of session

Tags: php, random, random-seed

Background: If you seed your prng, it will print out the same random sequence. So, if I tell you that I used the seed 123 and I got 1, 5, 2, 4. Then, you can use the seed 123 and get 1, 5, 2, 4.

What I want to do in the most simple case... I make a web page that lets you enter a seed. Then, it shows you one random number and a "next" link. You click the next link and get the next random number. The problem is that the page accessed when clicking "next" has no relationship with the previous page. So, it is not based on the seed entered.

What I'm trying to do, and I am obviously overlooking something, is to maintain the seed during the session. I can srand to seed the rand for the first random number. Then, I need to store the updated seed in the session so the next time the user shows up I can srand with the proper next seed. Is there an opposite to srand? I don't want to seed the rand. I want to get the value required to make it start in the current state the next load.

Comment: Keep a seed value and a count in session: on each request, seed the prng, then generate random numbers up to count, and discard them.... generate the next random number, and increment the count

Comment: @MarkBaker - probably the only way to do it; PRNGS don't usually expose the internals necessary to do it otherwise.  That, or write your own, but I'm not sure if any of the well-known implementations even have the concept of an intermediate seed...

Comment: hmm... looks like a [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) does what you want, although you'll probably have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that I'd have to implement it myself. That isn't a big deal, but I didn't want to do it if I didn't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can workaround your issue by always reinitializing the srand with the last random number generated. You "mix up" the seeds but you still have a reproducable way to generate random numbers.

Here is some code :

```
function getNextRandomNumber()
{
    $mySeed = 0; // a default seed value
    if (isset($_SESSION['seed']))
    {
        // continue our seed serie
        $mySeed = $_SESSION['seed'];
    }
    else if (isset($_GET['seed']))
    {
        // reinitialize the seed serie with a user's value
        $mySeed = $_GET['seed'];
    }
    // reproducable srand value
    srand($mySeed);

    // generate the random number
    $rand = rand();
    // We save the seed
    $_SESSION['seed'] = $rand;

    return $rand;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I just did - with a slight difference. I used mt_rand and I generated the random between min/max values. Then, I made a second rand (unbounded) for the next seed. I tested it on 1,000,000 iterations with a bound of 1 to 20 and each value showed up 5% of the time.